# IsolatedStorage Delete audio file on wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, delete-file, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

IsolatedStorage Delete audio file on windows phone 8

[image: The Problem]

In this pictures I test isostore.DeleteFile(_tempFileName); , but didn't work

this line of code when I saved the audio file and (working) 
[image]